# 3cx or other IP PBX - can this be done without a paid incoming/outgoing number

Tags: networking, voip

I am looking to setup 3cx for family use with a couple android devices. Do I need to buy a SIP trunk if I just want to connect the ony 4 devices to each other?

If i do get a line, can I only have 1 incoming/outgoing call going from the devices? Could they call each other without using the SIP line.

I have a computer that will run the 3cx(or other... elastix).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A SIP trunk is only required to connect to the PSTN, it is not required for the SIP clients to communicate with each other. Your real issue would most likely be routing SIP through your firewall, most SIP servers require a Session Border Controller of some kind if the server sits behind a firewall or router, especially if NAT is involved. Assuming you can get over that hurdle, communication between the SIP clients should be simple.

Comment: Should be able to follow instructions for port forwarding and configuration.